# Varnish cluster and Last-Modified

Tags: http-headers, varnish, bundling-and-minification

In our setup we have 3 varnish servers in front of a cluster of backend servers. Varnish is load-balancing using round-robin. Resently we started using bundles for css and js. Each generated bundle gets a Last-Modified header from the backend server. We store the bundles for 24 hours.

The problem is, that when varnish retrieves the bundle from a backend server, the Last-Modified is slightly different depending on wich backend server is hit at which time. The result is, that approx. 50% of the browser requests get a 200 response instead of a 302 when asking with a conditional "If-Modified-Since" header.

I'm looking for some suggestions on how to solve this. Manipulating headers leaving the server could be a solution, but somehow it seems wrong. Having one backend server is unfortunately also not an option, due to scalability and deployment issues.

Comment: What about setting a primary backend for just the bundles directory/path, and the rest of backends as backups/fallbacks. Not perfect, but simple to setup and will give in normal circumstances the desired effect without impacting single point of failure. (or alternative, but the bundles on a cdn)

Comment: Hi Marcel. But in a rolling deployment scenario, you would still have the posibillity of getting bundles from at least two different servers. Kind of stuck here. I think i will look into manipulating the headers. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Agree, not perfect. what process/code handles the bundle generation? ie is it an option to set a consistent ETag instead across the backend servers independent from the timestamp?